# Multi-monitor Setup with Widescreen and Two 19 inch Screens

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am looking to get a setup with a single widescreen monitor ~22" in the middle and a 19" one on either side. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to find screens that would work for this as it is quite hard to find different sized screens where the dot pitch matches, which is rather annoying.

Has anyone put together something like this and have any recommendations for screens that may work? I'm somewhat flexible about the sizes, but don't want to stray too far.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the Dell UltraSharp line.

I have a 2208WS (22" widescreen) and a 1907 (19" regular) in a dual monitor setup at work. The screens are nearly the same size vertically and have very close resolutions - 1600x1050 and 1280x1024. There is no noticeable size change when moving a window from one screen to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there aren't any inexpensive combos that will match the dot pitch exactly.  smckinney's suggestion is your best option on a budget.  If it's not good enough for you, your only options are a pair of 20" 1600x1200 and a 23" 1920x1200, or the same resolutions in 21 and 24" sizes.  The price problem is that the 20/21/23" monitors in those classes were all only available in higher end *VA/IPS panels, vs the cheaper TN type.  VA and IPS monitors are noticably higher quality (most apparent in vertical viewing angles) but command a 50 or 100% price premium.  This is made somewhat worse by the fact that there aren't any new 20/21/23" panels in the needed resolution.  The 21" is the worst; AFAIK the only display in the needed size is the NEC2190 which was aimed at profesional photographers/video editors and runs >$1k new.  NEC occasionally unloads refurbs of this on their website for a more reasonable price.  NEC refurbs have the backlight replaced and should last almost as long as new; so the only thing you'd be giving up is a few years of warranty coverage if you went that way.

Answer (score 0):

I Have two 19" monitors with equal resolution at home: everything is pretty easy with setup like that.

But there was some issue when 32" display was connected to 17" notebook as a second display. Issue was simple: resolution that could be supported by both screens had to be selected. Notebook supports wide range of sizes whilst TV-screen had very narrow one.

So that's the only thing that can mess up your idea. But as you're looking forward normal displays you'll be able to easily adjust them. **But**: I have no experience with systems set up for three monitors at once :)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing I can tell you, being a triple screen setup user, is make sure the resolution is the same. It is visually jarring to have a window change sizes or jump around. I recommend personally 4:3. I have found that my three 20 inch 4:3 HP LP2065's are the BEST choice I could have made, and I'm so glad I didn't go the widescreen route. The 4:3 is much more comfortable to the eye, and the dual/triple means that space is increased so the widescreen argument about having more windows open doesn't really apply too much.

Best wishes!